# MongoDB match expression query not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

MongoDb query match expression not working.

I have a posts collection and want to return only those posts which match the user Id of the user who created it but my query does not seem to be working.

**Sample Dataset**

```
[
  // 1
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("6257047cffd61ab62864c1ae"),
    "type": "A",
    "source": "B",
    "status": "A",
    "user": ObjectId("622b55ff0b0af6b049c387d3")
  },
  // 2
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("6257047cffd61ab62864c1ad"),
    "type": "B",
    "source": "A",
    "status": "A",
    "user": ObjectId("622b55ff0b0af6b049c387d3")
  },
  // 3
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("6257047cffd61ab62864c1ce"),
    "type": "A",
    "source": "C",
    "status": "B",
    "user": ObjectId("622b55ff0b0af6b049c387d3")
  },
  // 4
  {"_id": ObjectId("6257047cffd61ab62864c1cb"),
  "type": "A",
  "source": "B",
  "status": "C",
  "user": ObjectId("622b56250b0af6b049c387d6")
}
]
```

**MongoDb Query:-**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      paramType: "All",
      paramSource: "All",
      paramStatus: "All",
      
    },
    
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          {
            user: ObjectId("622b55ff0b0af6b049c387d3")
          },
          {
            $or: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$paramType",
                  "All"
                ],
                
              },
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$paramType",
                  "$type"
                ],
                
              },
              
            ],
            
          },
          {
            $or: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$paramSource",
                  "All"
                ],
                
              },
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$paramSource",
                  "$source"
                ],
                
              },
              
            ],
            
          },
          {
            $or: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$paramStatus",
                  "All"
                ],
                
              },
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$paramStatus",
                  "$status"
                ],
                
              },
              
            ],
            
          },
          
        ],
        
      },
      
    },
    
  },
  {
    $setWindowFields: {
      output: {
        totalCount: {
          $count: {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      createdAt: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $skip: 0
  },
  {
    $limit: 6
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "paramSource": false,
      "paramStatus": false,
      "paramType": false,
      
    }
  }
])
```

**Query Output:-**

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("6257047cffd61ab62864c1ae"),
    "source": "B",
    "status": "A",
    "totalCount": 4,
    "type": "A",
    "user": ObjectId("622b55ff0b0af6b049c387d3")
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("6257047cffd61ab62864c1ad"),
    "source": "A",
    "status": "A",
    "totalCount": 4,
    "type": "B",
    "user": ObjectId("622b55ff0b0af6b049c387d3")
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("6257047cffd61ab62864c1ce"),
    "source": "C",
    "status": "B",
    "totalCount": 4,
    "type": "A",
    "user": ObjectId("622b55ff0b0af6b049c387d3")
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("6257047cffd61ab62864c1cb"),
    "source": "B",
    "status": "C",
    "totalCount": 4,
    "type": "A",
    "user": ObjectId("622b56250b0af6b049c387d6")
  }
]
```

The query does not work output contains posts created by all users it is not filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$match` part should look like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/h6BBENpwfNt):

```
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          user: ObjectId("622b55ff0b0af6b049c387d3")
        },
        {
          $or: [{paramType: {$eq: "All"}},
            {$expr: {$eq: ["$paramType", "$type"]}}
          ]
        },
        {
          $or: [{paramSource: {$eq: "All"}},
            {$expr: {$eq: ["$paramSource", "$type"]}}
          ]
        },
        {
          $or: [{paramStatus: {$eq: "All"}},
            {$expr: {$eq: ["$paramStatus", "$type"]}}
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

The `$expr` should only be assigned to cases where both values are in the document. This query returns 3 / 4 documents, the ones in which `user: ObjectId("622b55ff0b0af6b049c387d3")`

BTW, the last 3 conditions on this `$match` stage are redundant, as they will always be true, since the query sets them with the value 'All' on the former stage

Comment: actually I would need those conditions as I would use a variable for param and it will have a value of All or some filter condition anyway thanks this works.